# How does pandas.DataFrame got converted to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

I am new to ML,pandas and numpy.

I was going through a jupyter file of a linear regression program. There I saw
`dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\First ML Projects/winequality.csv')`.

When I did `type(dataset)` I got `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. Makes sense because dataset was created using a method of `pd`

Then, there was this code,

`X = dataset[['fixed acidity', 'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', 'chlorides', 'free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', 'pH', 'sulphates','alcohol']].values`

When I did `type(X)` I got `numpy.ndarray`.

First question: Why was the `X` not in `pandas.DataFrame` format?

Second: When there was no mention of numpy or np, how did it get converted to `numpy.ndarray`?

Third: What is the difference between pandas.DataFrame and numpy.ndarray as the both are storing data?

Comment: If `df` is a dataframe then `df.values` is a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `X = dataset[['fixed acidity', ..., 'alcohol']]` means that the DataFrame is being indexed by a list of column names. The result is still a DataFrame, containing only the selected columns. But then the method [pd.df.values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is applied to this DataFrame. This method returns the underlying NumPy array.
2. Pandas is built on top of NumPy, so if you have numerical data in a DataFrame, they will be stored in NumPy arrays under the hood. Again, the method [pd.df.values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is what makes this explicit here.
3. NumPy arrays are optimized for numerical data, whereas Pandas works with all kinds of data. Pandas has more ways to munge the data in a DataFrame, but it is generally slower than pure NumPy. A [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) is two-dimensional, with an index for the rows and labels for the columns, whereas a NumPy [ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) can have any number of dimensions but does not have any labels.

Comment: `Pandas is built on top of NumPy` That clears everything. I was under the impression that pandas and numpy are two different things and hence was having a hard time to understand from where does numpy came out of nowhere. Thanks for your answer.